# IIS7 ASP classic Mysql and ODBC Driver problems

Tags: mysql, iis-7, asp-classic, odbc, windows-server-2008

We have just moved our high volume ASP classic website from Windows server 2003, 32bit, iis6, Mysql to server 2008, 64bit, IIS7.

We are experiance some truncated data and page slow downs on some pages that make a lot of calls on the DB.  We are using ODBC Driver 3.51.

We are pretty sure it is the ODBC driver but have no idea how to fix it

Any ideas

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple.  Many of the sql queries on the site are handled badly by ODBC Driver 3.51.

Slowness and truncation of data being some of the obvious problems and can often be fixed by rewriting the way loops through data can be handled.  Handling a lot of processing in memory has also helped.

We are going to test a newer version of ODBC client soon to see if that is faster and more stable.

Comment: The different ODBC client worked but then we rewrote everything into a new PHP framework. Much more satisfying.